# Method overloading as a static polymorphism in C#

Tags: c#, oop, methods, operator-overloading, polymorphism

How method overloading is considerd as a static polymorphism in c#?

Comment: Is that a question for school? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to google (if you type in "define static polymorphism"):

> Polymorphism implemented at compile-time; generics.

At compile time it is known exactly which overload to call (based on arguments).  If compiler cannot determine this, it generates an error.

The only exception is the dynamic keyword.